# git is unable to properly determine the terminal width (git-bash, windows)

Tags: windows, bash, terminal, git, git-bash

[image: screenshot of terminal with the issue]

As you can see in the screenshot, the terminal is currently 100 characters wide, and both methods of detecting such that I'm aware of are returning the correct value. Despite this, unless I explicitly set the `--width` option to `100`, `git column` seems to fall back to `80` as the terminal width. This behavior isn't necessarily unexpected, as [the documentation for `git column`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-column#Documentation/git-column.txt---widthltwidthgt) states:

> `--width=<width>`
> Specify the terminal width. ***By default git column will detect the terminal width, or fall back to 80 if it is unable to do so***.

So it seems obvious that git is unable to determine the number of columns in my terminal. The question then is: why? I was unable to locate any documentation about how this detection is done.

Here's some (possibly) relevant system information:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.43.0.windows.1
$ systeminfo | grep -i 'OS Name\|OS Version'
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.22631 N/A Build 22631
```

I can provide any other relevant sections of my bash configuration files and/or other details about my system's setup.

Comment: Try `alias git='COLUMNS=tput cols git'` (more in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75482606/how-can-width-of-git-stat-be-configured)).

Comment: @harrymc indeed, this "fixes" the problem, but it's a rather unsatisfying solution. I think it does point in the right direction though as to what the root cause may be: for whatever reason, even though `COLUMNS` has the correct value in the parent shell, that value is not in scope anymore when git needs to use it.

Comment: @harrymc also, for other to reference, could you edit the alias to be: `alias git='COLUMNS=$(tput cols) git'`

Comment: @harrymc without the subshell, invoking any git command results in `bash: cols: command not found`

Comment: Sorry, but comments can only be edited during 4 minutes, so now it's too late. Your comment will have to do the job.

Comment: Better yet, you could post it as an answer with caveats that it's not the best solution possible

Answer (score 1):

I found interesting information in the post
[LINES and COLUMNS environmental variables lost in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48016366/165358)
which might explain the problem:

> Often, on modern systems, the `$COLUMNS` and `$LINES` variables are
> *not* environment variables. The shell sets these values dynamically after each command and we usually cannot access them from
> non-interactive scripts. Some programs respect these values if we
> *export* them, but this behavior isn't standardized or universally supported.
>
> Bash sets these variables in the scope of the *process* (not the
> environment) when we enable the `checkwinsize` option using:
>
> ```
> shopt -s checkwinsize
> ```
>
> Many systems enable this option for us in a default or system-wide
> startup file (*/etc/bashrc* or similar), so we need to remember
> that these variables may not always be available. On some systems,
> such as Cygwin, this option is *not* enabled for us, so Bash doesn't
> set `$COLUMNS` and `$LINES` unless we execute the line above or add it
> to our *~/.bashrc*.

Your case is probably one where the columns are not set for some
reason, and you may workaround the problem as described above.

In the case that this still doesn't work for whatever reason,
the final workaround will be:

```
alias git='COLUMNS=$(tput cols) git'
```